# What is the limit of the $n$-th power of the shift operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T: \ell^2 (\mathbb R) \to \ell^2 (\mathbb R)$ be the left shift operator $(x_1,x_2,x_3, \dots) \mapsto (x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots)$. Let $T^n$ denote a left shift by $n$ positions.

What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} T^n$? Is it $0$?

Edit: I want to have $T^n \to 0$. Let $B(\ell^2(\mathbb R))$ denote the space of bounded linear operators on $\ell^2$ and let us endow it with the strong operator topology or whatever is convenient to achieve the goal.

Comment: What is the norm of $T^n$? (What is $T^n(e_{n+1})$?)

Comment: In what topology? Strongly (and hence weakly) operator, we have $T^n \to 0$. In norm, as @DavidMitra said, $T^n$ does not converge.

Comment: @martini I was thinking in the norm topology. But what I'm really trying to do is to come up with an example with $T^n \to 0$ so I'll use the strong operator topology.

Comment: @martini I'm not familiar with SOT but I'm reading about it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that on $B(\ell^2\def\R{\mathbb R})$ we have different topologies in which we can talk about convergence of $(T^n)$. As $\{T^n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ is a norm-bounded set, many of these topologies coincide, for an overview of the topologies see for example [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologies_on_the_set_of_operators_on_a_Hilbert_space).

I will discuss three topologies here (the IMHO most important ones for norm bounded sets): The norm topology, the strong operator topology, the weak operator topology:

- In the *norm topology*, $(T^n)$ does not converge, as David wrote in his comment, to see this, observe, that - for example $$ (T^{n+1} - T^n)(e_{n+2}) = e_1 - e_2 $$ And hence $\|T^{n+1} - T^n\| \ge \sqrt 2$, so $(T^n)$ is not norm-Cauchy.
- In the *strong operator topology*, we have $T^n \to 0$. To see this, let $x \in \ell^2$. Then 
  $$ \|T^nx\|^2 =\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty|x_k|^2 \to 0 $$
  so $T^n x \to 0$ for each $x$, that is $T^n \to 0$ strongly operator.
- In the *weak operator topology*, we have $T^n \to 0$, as this topology is weaker than the strong operator topology, so strong convergence implies weak convergence.

Comment: I'm sorry but [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology#Strong_operator_topology) it is stated that unilateral shift does not converge to $0$ in SOT. Is Wikipedia wrong?

Comment: @tomb. They seem to talk about the right shift $S\colon (x_1, x_2, \ldots) \to (0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ there. For this operator $S^n \to 0$ (weakly operator), but $S^n x \not\to 0$ for any $x \ne 0$, so $S^n \not\to 0$ (strongly operator). This example also shows (as $S = T^*$) that $T \mapsto T^*$ is not strongly operator continuous.